# Application insights reuses instrumentation key

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am creating Web app and Application Insights resource using ARM template in VSTS release process. Deployment mode is set to Incremental. While I am developing the solution, I quite often delete the Azure App Service and Application insights resource (manually) and run the VSTS release process to my dev azure resource group. The process creates App insights in one step and App service in next one and sets the Instrumentation key for App service.  I don't change the names of the resources.  Sometimes I notice that the new Application Insights resource gets the same Instrumentation Key as the one I deleted but the App Service retrieves new value for Instrumentation Key. It looks like the App Insights is not properly created although there was no errors in VSTS release process. Has anyone encounter similar problem? it makes me a bit worried about the 'repeatability' of the release process

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this as well. Azure sometimes displays the same key as of last time for a newly generated application insights resource. However, this key will automatically change to a new one after a few hours. Seems like Azure has got a Ghost Key problem.